# perl redirectmatch regular expression

Tags: perl

Could you please some one help me write a regular expression for the following requirement.

PATTERN written in apache httpd.conf

**RedirectMatch ^/$ https://demo.test.com/xyz/test/DemoWelcomePage**

I have rewritten a pattern to match but it failing in perl.

**$FS_URL="demo.test.com";
searching the Pattern using grep - "RedirectMatch\s\^/\$\s(https\|http)\://($FS_URL).*"**

Could you correct me regular expression condition.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, what you want. Please, give a simple example of url and redirect url. What regular expression have you created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^/$
```

what it means

^ match at the start of a line
/ means match a /character
$ match at the end of the line

So it will match a line that has exactly one / in it

In the context of Apache this means the root page of your site only, ie
`http://www.example.com/`

All other pages on the site do not match

Not sure what your second regexp is trying to achieve, you mention perl but don't give any context - sorry